# HttpURLConnection: No data in the POST request

Tags: java, django-rest-framework, httpurlconnection, androidhttpclient

I have created a Django Rest server. And I am trying to POST a JSON content in java using HttpURLConnection. However, when I am registering OutputStream in java, the server get a POST request with no JSON content. Hence the server rejecting the request with HTTP response code 400. I did write JSON data just after registering OutputSream. May be POST has been made before writing to OutputStream. The following is the code in JAVA.

```
    public static void post(HttpURLConnection urlConnection1)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/");
    byte[] authStr=Base64.encodeBase64("sp:password".getBytes());
    String enc=new String(authStr);

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ enc);
    try {

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        urlConnection
                .setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);


        OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        writeStream(out);
        out.flush();

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        readStream(in);
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

}

private static void writeStream(OutputStream out) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        JSONObject grp = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject gp = new JSONObject();
        gp.put("id", "g3bj25");
        gp.put("from", "someone");

        out.write(gp.toString().getBytes());

        System.out.println(gp.toString());
    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Do I have to make any changes in server side so that it waits for content?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your URL is not complete, **the name of the script is missing**.

```
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/");
```

supposes that you are calling `http://127.0.0.1/message/index.php` but here you're not allowed to let the `index.php` (or whatever) implicit.

The script gets called, but the POST data is not sent, or it is truncated by the Webserver when handling the request. I had the same problem and spent hours until I found the reason. Then I did not dig further to find out exactly *where* the POST data gets dropped.